# mysql number rows than selectimg and updating info in the row

Tags: mysql, sql

This works:

```
set @type = ' ';  set@num = 1; select * from (select *, @num:= if(@type = firstname, @num + 1, 1) as num, @type := firstname  as dummy from table order by id desc) as table  where table.firstname = 'Mike' and table.num = '2'
```

This doesn't

```
set @type = ' ';  set@num = 1; Update table set table.firstname = 'me' where (select table.firstname from (select *, @num:= if(@type = firstname, @num + 1, 1) as num, @type := firstname as dummy from personal) as table where table.firstname ='Mike' and table.num = '2');
```

This updates all rows

```
set @type = '';  set@num = 1; Update personal set personal.firstname = 'Mike' where personal.firstname in (select personal.firstname from (select firstname, lastname, password, id, @num:= if(@type = firstname, @num + 1, 1) as num, @type := firstname  as dummy from personal order by id desc) as t where t.firstname = 'mike' and num = '1');
```

Any thoughts onto update a single selected row

Comment: try to update going off the id of the table instead of Name, since there could be multiple 'Mike'.

Comment: what are you trying to do? why are you ordering by id? with your variable shouldn't you be ordering by firstname?

Answer (score 0):

please try this. If you're trying update the last created record of Name 'Mike'.

```
set @type = '';  set@num = 1; 
Update personal set personal.firstname = 'NewName' 
 where personal.id in 
 (select t.id from 
  (select firstname, lastname, password, id, 
         @num:= if(@type = firstname, @num + 1, 1)  as num, 
        @type := firstname  as dummy 
      from personal order by firstname,id desc) 
  as t where t.firstname = 'Mike' and num = '1');
```

alternately you can just run an Update without using any variable, if you want to update the Last Created record of the name 'Mike'.

```
Update personal set personal.firstname = 'NewName' 
 where personal.id in 
     (select t.id from 
        (select id
         from personal 
         where firstname = 'Mike'
         order by id desc LIMIT 1
        )as t 
      );
```

Or even better you can just simply run this update

```
Update personal set personal.firstname = 'NewName' 
       where firstname = 'Mike'
Order by id DESC
Limit 1;
```

Comment: I will eventually need to write it in php too

Comment: Appears to be working correctly. Now to transfer it to a php script.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I do need both the id and the row variables.